# Bash pipeline not working with asterisks

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

I am using the following pipeline: `ls -F | ls *"*"`
in attempt to find the executable files since ls -F adds an asterisks to executable files, but for some reason this will not work, why is this?

Comment: Probably because you want grep there, not another `ls`.

Comment: @pvg that does not work either